# After convert string to const *json, when pasing json object, shows failed: (IsObject()), how to solve this?

Tags: c++, json, string, rapidjson

After convert `string strjson` to `const char* json`, when interate, shows 
failed: (`IsObject()`), function `FindMember`,failed, I don't understand why showed this, I think this the `json` object is correct format.

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  rapid
//
//  Created by Shi Yan on 10/7/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Shi Yan. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include "rapidjson.h"
#include "document.h"
#include <fstream>   
using namespace std;
using namespace rapidjson;   
void readjson(){
    ifstream handle("meta_Books.json");
    if(handle.is_open()){
        //cout<<"open success"<<endl;
        const char* json;
        string strjson;
        int i=1;
        while(getline(handle,strjson)){
            if(i>4)
                break;
            cout<<strjson<<endl;
            cout<<strjson.length()<<endl;
            i++;             
            json=strjson.c_str();
            cout<<"*********************"<<endl;
            cout<<*json<<endl;
            StringStream s (json);
            Document document;
            document.ParseStream(s);
            Value::ConstMemberIterator itr = document.FindMember("asin");
            cout<<itr->name.GetString()<<" = "<< itr->value.GetString()<<endl;
        }
    }
}   
int main() {
    readjson();
    return 0;
}
```

I think the format of json object , so why failed?

[image]

As you can see , the `getline()` method works well, because the output of string is an complete string

[image]

Comment: Note that this line `cout<<*json<<endl;` is outputting a single character from the char array (by dereferencing `const char*` you get `char`)

Comment: But in the first two output, I get the right answer for query the value of key="asin", however, when processing the third object, it failed. Parse the second object is normal, so I think it doesn't matter with not start with an object is its root. But why parse failed?

Comment: I have known why get the first char, thanks Steve

Comment: "*because the output of string is an complete string*" - that is not what your 1st screenshot shows. The 2nd screenshot does not match your code. The 1st screenshot does, and clearly shows `strjson` is NOT a complete JSON object when the error occurs. It is being split into 2 lines, neither of which parses correctly

Answer (score 2):

The assertion error means that `FindMember()` is being called on a `Value` that does not represent a JSON object (`IsObject()` is false).

Since there is only 1 `FindMember()` in the code you showed, that implies that `document.IsObject()` is false when `document.FindMember()` fails. Either the JSON you are parsing does not start with an object in its root, or the parse failed.  Neither condition of which you are testing for in your code.

If I had to guess (and please don't make people guess!), the failing JSON document likely contains an unencoded line break in it (that is not illegal inside of JSON string values).  That would cause `std::getline()` to exit prematurely, thus causing parsing issues.
 The 1st screenshot you showed supports that conclusion, showing that `strjson` is being split between 2 separate "lines" when the error occurs.

Rather than using `std::getline()` to read the file line-by-line, risking errors on embedded line breaks, I suggest you try using RapidJSON's [`BasicIStreamWrapper`](http://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_basic_i_stream_wrapper.html) class to read the file document-by-document instead.  `ParseStream()` has a `kParseStopWhenDoneFlag` flag that allows parsing multiple root documents from a single input stream:

> kParseStopWhenDoneFlag
>
> After parsing a complete JSON root from stream, stop further processing the rest of stream. When this flag is used, parser will not generate kParseErrorDocumentRootNotSingular error.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>   
#include "rapidjson.h"
#include "document.h"
#include "istreamwrapper.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace rapidjson;   

void readjson()
{
    ifstream handle("meta_Books.json");
    if (!handle.is_open())
    {
        // handle error...
        cout << "error opening file" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        BasicIStreamWrapper<ifstream> s(handle);
        for(int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
        {
            Document document;
            ParseResult pr = document.ParseStream<kParseStopWhenDoneFlag>(s);
            if (!pr)
            {
                // handle error...
                cout << "error parsing document " << i << endl;
            }
            else if (!document.IsObject())
            {
                cout << "document " << i << " is not an object" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                Value::ConstMemberIterator itr = document.FindMember("asin");
                if (itr != document.MemberEnd())
                    cout << "asin = " << itr->value.GetString() << endl;
                else
                    cout << "asin not found" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}   

int main()
{
    readjson();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried, it still cann't work,  
error: use of class template 'BasicIStreamWrapper' requires template arguments BasicIStreamWrapper s(handle);